# past-future tense

Tags: future-time

Say, I am carrying a chainsaw towards a tree. In that case I *am about to* saw that tree down.

Suppose someone stops me and asks me to cut that tree.

How can I politely inform them that I am about to do that and I got that idea before they asked me and without their "advice"?

I thought of "I was about to saw that tree down", but this phrase would be appropriate if I planned to fall the tree but something prevents me to do that.

Comment: You could clarify your intentions with "I was **already** about to cut down that tree."

Answer (score 2):

You could express it these ways

> I was **just about to** cut that tree down.
>   I was **just about to** do that *(before you interrupted me)*.
>   I was going to do **just that** *(before you started speaking to me)*.

the main point you seem to want to get across is that the idea already existed and was in action before the other person spoke to you.